# Greek yogurt substitute in baking?

Tags: baking, pie, yogurt, rhubarb

So this [recipe](https://www.goodfoodstories.com/rhubarb-lemon-pie/) (lemon rhubarb pie), calls for 3 tablespoons of Greek yogurt. What would be a good substitute for Greek yogurt? creme fraiche or cream cheese? 
And will it affect the final product?

Answer (score 4):

Given your options, I would go creme fraiche, you may need to thin with a small amount of milk or water to get to yogurt consistency.  Three tablespoons...you probably won't notice a difference.

Comment: Ok. What about plain yogurt? Would that work also?

Comment: Sure..no problem....if you need your plain yogurt to be Greek style, just put it in a coffee filter and allow it to drain for an hour or so.